# Ananconda kickstart

Tags: centos, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I am trying to use packer to build a virtual-box image using kickstart however the ananconda install fails due to lack of installation source and no software selection my kickstart script is shown below.

```
install
text
url --url=http://mirror.ukhost4u.com/centos/7.0.1406/isos/x86_64/

#Non relevant stuffs discarded

%packages --ignoremissing --excludedocs
@Base
@Core
@Development Tools
sudo
wget
curl
gettext-devel
openssl-devel
perl-CPAN
perl-devel
zlib-devel
%end
```

The install is for a Centos7 minimal image.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: the URL should be pointing to the `./os/x86_64` directory, not `/isos/x86_64/`.

```
url --url=http://mirror.ukhost4u.com/centos/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/
```

**Usual mistakes**: There are three typical errors I encountered:

- Wrong URL !
- Proxy problem (in corporate networks)
- DNS resolution problem